# Django cant seemto link css/js

Tags: python, html, css, django

I know this subject has been discussed before, but ive seen every tutorial and form in stack overflow but cant seem to understand why i cant link my CSS to my HTML file.

This is my  directory:
[image]

There are 2 apps, main & settings.

For the app named main, i was able to link the html file in from views.py.

I am now trying to link css & js to it.

I created a static file within the base directory that contains 3 folders, css,js,image.
[image]
I believe to have taken all the correct steps in order to connect CSS to HTML, but nothing happens.

I believe that the mistake is with the reference in the HTML file:

```
<link rel=”stylesheet” href=”{% static 'css/style_login.css' %}”>
```

But from what ive seen, it seems to be correct.

Bellow ive shared the settings, views, and HTML File.

Settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for auditor project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-$xb)9by$i@f+m3mnt$q&f%to&vjx)jgn#8(h!#(ymf2n)_09%_'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition



INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main.apps.MainConfig', # To tell Django that there is another 
    'settings',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'auditor.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'auditor.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),'media')
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = 10240 # higher than the count of fields





STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')



STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'auditor/static'),
)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def index(response):
    return render(response,"main/home.html",{})

def registerPage(request):
    
    form = UserCreationForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()




    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'main/register.html',context)
 

def loginPage(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request,'main/login.html',context)

#def login(response):
#    return render(response,"main/login.html",{})  



# Create your views here.
```

HTML:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <link rel=”stylesheet” href=”{% static 'css/style_login.css' %}”>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

</head>

<body>
    <div class="form">
      
        <ul class="tab-group">
          <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
        </ul>
        
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="signup">   
            <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>
            
            <form action="/" method="post">
            
            <div class="top-row">
              <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                  First Name<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
              </div>
          
              <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                  Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
            
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
            
            <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Get Started</button>
            
            </form>
    
          </div>
          
          <div id="login">   
            <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
            
            <form action="/" method="post">
            
              <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
            
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Password<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
            
            <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
            
            <button class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>
            
            </form>
    
          </div>
          
        </div><!-- tab-content -->
        
    </div> <!-- /form -->


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using only `STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'auditor/static')` and/or `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'auditor/static'),)`? Because for me, using only STATICFILES_DIR worked in my recent project

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried without avail, maybe im referencing to the wrong directory?

Comment: I believe your `PROJECT_DIR` is pointing to the wrong directoy, i.r not the app directory. Maybe replace it with the following code in your `settings.py` folder - `PROJECT_DIR= os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` and followed with my previous comment and let me know if it works

Comment: THanks!!!!IThat worked! I don't know how to give you rep, i guess you have to post the answer.

Comment: mark it as the correct answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i have answer in the comments above..

I believe your `PROJECT_DIR` is pointing to the wrong directoy, i.e not the app directory. Maybe replace it with the following code in your settings.py folder -
 `PROJECT_DIR= os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` and followed with using only `STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'auditor/static')` and/or `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'auditor/static'),)`